# Logarithmic spiral and helix curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Show that the following helix cure $\beta(t)=(ae^{bt} \cos t, ae^{bt} \sin t, ct) $ can be formed on the logarithmic spiral $\alpha(t)=(ae^{bt} \cos t, ae^{bt} \sin t) $

Can someone please help me. I dont know what to do in this question.

Comment: $\beta$ is not an helix.

Comment: To clarify your question, can you please add what "formed on" means?